# ошибка при сортировке dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas, сортировка

Имею фрейм:

```
d.groupby(['наименование']).describe()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пытаюсь отсортировать по колонке - 50% (медиана):

```
d.groupby(['наименование']).describe().sort_values(by='50%')
```

получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что не так, как сделать корректно?

Answer (score 1):

А вы посмотрите, какие у вас там собственно колонки:

```py
d.groupby(['наименование']).describe().columns
```

Там просто два уровня индекса у колонок, поэтому названия колонок представляют из себя кортежи. Полагаю, что нужная вам колонка называется как-то вроде `('* 1 000', '50%')` (за пробелы не уверен, по скриншоту их сложно угадать), соответственно сортировать по этой колонке нужно так:

```py
d.groupby(['наименование']).describe().sort_values(by=('* 1 000', '50%'))
```

Точное название колонки возьмите из результатов работы кода выше. Либо можно получить нужное название колонки в переменную, которую потом использовать:

```py
col = [col for col in df.groupby('customer_id')
       .describe().columns if col[1] == '50%']
```